# Move react component to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react. The code below is an example. ArrayExample is mapped and returned to the `div` component. Whenever I click the mapped `div` component, I want to change the value of the top of `div` `(position: 'absolute')` and place it on the right side according to the mapped `div` topBorder. Is there a way? I want to move it smoothly like an animation.

```js
    import React from "react";

    const sample = () => {
        const arrayExample = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"];
        return (
            <div
                style={{
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "column",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "500px",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3",
                }}
            >
                {arrayExample.map((v, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div
                            style={{
                                width: "50%",
                                padding: 50,
                                border: "1px solid black",
                                marginTop: 15,
                            }}
                            onClick={() => {
                                console.log("Event!")
                            }}
                        >
                            {v}
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
                <div style={{position: 'absolute', top: 70, right: '22%', backgroundColor: "#4285F4", width: 50, height: 150, borderRadius: 5}}>
                    moving screen(I want to Change top value)
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    };

    export default sample;
```

Answer (score 0):

On click of the item div, you need to figure out the distance of that div from the top, and then change the `top` css property of your right div according to that. To find this distance you can use `offsetTop` property. For animation you can use `transition` property. Here is the code:

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";

const Sample = () => {
    const arrayExample = ["AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC"];
    const rightDiv = useRef();
    const itemClickHandler = (i) => {
      const newTopHeight = document.getElementById("container").children[i].offsetTop;
      rightDiv.current.style.top = newTopHeight + 'px';
    }
    return (
        <div
            id="container"
            style={{
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                width: "100%",
                height: "500px",
                alignItems: "center",
                justifyContent: "center",
                backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3",
            }}
        >
            {arrayExample.map((v, i) => {
                return (
                    <div
                        key={i}
                        style={{
                            width: "50%",
                            padding: 50,
                            border: "1px solid black",
                            marginTop: 15,
                        }}
                        onClick={() => itemClickHandler(i)}
                    >
                        {v}
                    </div>
                );
            })}
            <div 
              ref={rightDiv}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute', 
                top: 70, 
                right: '22%', 
                backgroundColor: "#4285F4", 
                width: 50, 
                height: 150, 
                borderRadius: 5,
                transition: "top 0.5s ease-in-out"
              }}>
                moving screen(I want to Change top value)
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Sample;
```

You can see this in action here: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-curie-7mskj

Comment: If you find the answer useful, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your click handler you can get the current position of the clicked div in px, you can easily google how to do this this (relative to the page, not the viewport). I would suggest storing this value in state, call it something like activeItemOffsetTop, then just set top to the current state

Comment: Awesome! It's what I wanted. You're a genius. Thank you very much.